# .NET MVC unable to connect to MySQL after moving MySQL from RDS to RHEL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, rhel

Here is a bit of background information.
We moved our MySQL from AWS RDS (Relational Database Service) to a dedicated RHEL(Red Hat Enterprise Linux) server yesterday. Our .NET MVC application is unable to connect to the MySQL on RHEL after the move.

We have checked
a. RHEL server is assigned to the same security group as RDS.
b. port 3306 is open on RHEL
c. We can connect to MySQL on RHEL from web server (where .NET MVC application is hosted) via SSH using WorkBench.

I am not familiar with RHEL and I am not sure what settings on it might be blocking the connection. 
Can someone please provide some suggestions on what to check?
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: only a very generic message saying that the connection string is not correct and we need to check.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. It is to do with AWS security group setting.